# How to consume Platform event in JavaScript using CometD

Tags: integration, platform-event

I have a scenario, I want to subscribe to a PE in my salesforce org which is published by another salesforce org. I tried many ways but it is not working

by using cometd I'm able to subscribe the PE within the same org.

```
cometd.configure({
           url: 'https://<Salesforce_URL>/cometd/48.0/',
           requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth <Session_ID>'}
});
```

Is there any other way that we can subscribe PE in JavaScript from other org?